# Nixdorf 8812 Floating Point Numbers

Tags: java, math

I'm currenty working on a cashier system software and stumbled over 32 and 48bit Nixdorf 8812 floating point numbers. For example:

A4 38 76 00 00 00 or
A4 35 97 00

I suppose the first bit is for signed numbers, but what is the exponent?

Edit:
Found out that the first "4" means the position of the decimal separator. All numbers after that are packed decimals. The "A" seems to be the sign. But this is just a guess. The total amount matches btw!

Comment: Looks a bit like signed(?) BCD, maybe fixed point to me: -76.38, 97.35.

Comment: I don't get the downvote. Looks like an honest question, and also a hard to answer one

Comment: Maybe it's [decimal32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal32_floating-point_format) or a similar format?

Comment: This place is now full of over-eager zealots -.-

Or was is over-zealous ea... eagl...? no.

Comment: Btw., speaking of which, it's "currently working" with LY at the end of current 

Comment: Maybe the A4 is an ASCII $ sign with the high bit set?

Comment: You're going to have to ask Nixdorf.

Comment: I already send a mail to the Nixdorf customer support ;)

Comment: @StephanFrigger you should post it as an answer and accept your own answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example: A4 35 97 00 -> 35,97

The "4" was the decimal separator. I didnt find out what the "A" means.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a variant of IEEE 754? :)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point

Can you create arbitrary floating point numbers at look at their binary representation?

Like 0.0, +0.0, -0.0, +1.0, -1.0

And if you can, could you post them here?

Comment: no, IEEE-754 has no 48-bit standard, and this Nixdorf machine was really old so it probably doesn't use IEEE-754